# Break when any member of an class (or object) called

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-framework-version

I am currently debugging my application. (.Net Framework 4.6.2)
I have an instance of a class, that is somehow getting modified when performing a specific function (on debugging). I would now like to understand, **what** accessed and changed the object.

```
 void PerformCalculationWithObject(MyClass obj)
 {
      DoSomething(obj); // calls a lot of different operations
                        // which sometimes modify obj, and sometimes not.
 }
```

But the class is large and complex, and many function are called underneath the function.

I am aware that my biggest issue is the lack of good object-design in this legacy code, which leads to this problem.

So the question is, if there is a **possibility to auto-break**, when some member of the class (maybe even just fron specific instance) is called (without putting plenty of break-points).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS 2019 and .NET Core 3.0 there are data breakpoints that can be set on an object from the watch window. Just right click on an expression in the watch window (in this case add a watch for `obj`) and then choose "Break when value changes".

More info on this is over at: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/break-when-value-changes-data-breakpoints-for-net-core-in-visual-studio-2019/

I appreciate this might not help you as you're debugging a legacy application but perhaps either it can run .NET Core 3 while debugging or some other user will find this answer useful.

Comment: This would actually be what I want. However, it does not work with .net freamwork, just with .net core as far as I see.

Comment: You are right. It is only for .net core. Let me update the answer to make that clear.

Comment: But in general, you hit the neil with this feature, that's what I wanted - but im .net framework. I marked it as useful and added keyword to my question. Maybe some day there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Something I usually do in such cases is change the class member varibles which I suspect to change to properties with a get and set method and then put a breakpoint int the set method.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to avoid, as there are many to possibilities, and of often face this issue.